# PhpStorm meta and multiple factory arguments

Tags: php, phpstorm

I've been trying to setup the .phpstorm.meta.php file for factory methods but I can't get it to fully work. It works for factory methods that only takes 1 argument, but if there are 2 or more arguments, it doesn't work.

So basically, all factory methods that takes more than 1 argument is affected, especially splat arguments i.e `factory(string $className, ...$ctorArgs)`.

Here is an example of my meta file;

```
<?php
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override(
        \ContainerInterface::make(0),
        map([
            '' => '@',
        ])
    );
}
```

This is the signature;

```
<?php
interface ContainerInterface{
    /* @return mixed */
    public function make (string $className, ...$ctorArgs);
}
```

And here is an example of expected/results;

```
<?php
$container->make(MyClass::class, "hello", "world")-> // Nothing is indicated here, should indicate MyClass props/methods
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Apparently since 17.2 they decided to limit factory methods to only one argument. In previous version, and with the old syntax, this was not limited. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38403

Comment: Can you please create and share a simple project that would contain the minimal needed classes? It's kind of works OK for Laravel: `\App::make()` , `$this->app->make()` , `app()` -- those that I have tested for `log` service -- with and without additional parameter (PhpStorm 2017.2.4)

Comment: Note: the function declarations in Laravel use optional parameters (default values) and not variadic param `...$param` -- maybe that's what's makes the difference.

Comment: @LazyOne You are using a PhpStorm version (17.2.4) that isn't completely broken, it works for set number of parameters, but not splat operators. In 17.3 or later they removed support for factory methods with more than 1 argument. Thus my understanding when i made my first comment here was somewhat wrong, but still applies to the splat operator.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/putj7um5j/ -- That's 2017.3 . If you provide simple sample project (4-5 files pretty much) I can try and mess around (yeah, too lazy to make them myself). Right now it could be specific to ` '' => '@',` rule (as in my example `log` has dedicated entry) etc.

Comment: Literally, my example in the question is all you need. Paste the container interface and then create a null variable, then tell the IDE that it's a container by; `/* @var $variable ContainerInterface */`, then you can try all you want.

Comment: The better place for this is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Note: I'm PHPSTORM_META author and maintainer

Comment: @AlexeyGopachenko Thanks, I did post a bug report on Nov.30 (WI-38987) and it was marked as duplicate of an issue from October (WI-38403).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a known bug; https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38403